# fetch data from multiple tables using sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, linq

I have a problem in sql ,
Suppose i have  a main table "Project" and its project consists of 2 different details like project members,project files.
Now case is that project may consists of 10 members and 4 files i.e corresponding to one project ID.

How could i fetch data from three tables and show in UI.

```
var qry = (from p in dbModel.tbl_PROJECT
           join q in dbModel.tbl_PROJECTxFILE
           on p.ProjectID equals q.ProjectID
           into list2

           from l2 in list2.DefaultIfEmpty()
           join f in dbModel.tbl_FILE
           on l2.FileID equals f.FileID
           into list3

           from l3 in list3.DefaultIfEmpty()
            join c in dbModel.tbl_PROJECTxCOMPONENT
           on p.ProjectID equals c.ProjectID
            into list8

           from l8 in list8.DefaultIfEmpty()
           join a in dbModel.tbl_PROJECTCOMPONENT
           on l8.ProjectComponentID equals a.ProjectComponentID
            into list9

           from l9 in list9.DefaultIfEmpty()
           where p.ProjectID == projectId
           select new ProjectDetails1
           {

               ProjectTtile = p.ProjectTtile,
               ProjectIcon = p.ProjectIcon,
               ProjectDescription = p.ProjectDescription,
               ExpectedDeadline = p.ExpectedDeadline,
               FileName = l3.FileName,
               FilePath = l3.FilePath,
               FileSize = l3.FileSize,
               UploadDate = l3.UploadDate,
               FileID = l3.FileID,
               Title = l9.Title,
               ColorId = l9.ColorID,
               ProjectComponentID=l9.ProjectComponentID,
           }).ToList();
```

Comment: What is your expected outcome?

Comment: @PatrickHofman i need data from memebers(data=10) and file(data=5) table both

Comment: where 10 and 5 are number of records

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to Filter specific rows? then you need to use Offset and Fetch clause, for example....You first specify the OFFSET clause indicating how many rows you want to skip (0 if you don’t want to skip any); you then optionally specify the FETCH clause indicating how many rows you want to filter, hope this helps. Thanks